# Probability related to circles

Tags: probability

There is a circle of radius 'r'. A chord is chosen at random, what is the probability that the chord is a diameter of the circle?

Comment: It should be zero.

Comment: I thought the same but it can be chosen at any point is time

Comment: How does time matter here?

Comment: "*A chord is chosen* **at random**"  You will need to be far more specific about the process of selection.  In any case, under most reasonable interpretations of the problem, such as both ends of the chord being chosen independently and uniformly at random, the probability that the cord is a diameter will indeed be zero.  This should be easy to see for the method of selection I describe as given any specific first selection of an endpoint, there are uncountably infinitely many selections for the second end point, only one of which results in the chord being a diameter.

Comment: You should read about [Bertrand's Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_paradox_(probability)), another probability problem related to chords on a circle where the answer to the probability problem changes depending on what method of selection you used which highlights and emphasizes the importance of adequately defining problems like this.

Comment: Why am I down voted for the question?

Comment: Suggested reasons to downvote: "*This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful.*"  Your question certainly fits those descriptions.  You showed no effort in having attempted the problem yourself, including but not limited to sharing your own thoughts or sharing what related information you've read.  Further, your question suffers the fatal flaw of being ill-defined, as mentioned earlier, and so is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is similar (in a way) to Bertrand's Paradox: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_paradox_(probability).

This random selection is not clear as there any many different ways a chord can be randomly selected, leading to different weights on whether a chord will be a diameter or not. If there is more information to the problem that would be helpful, otherwise there is not enough information to give a clear answer.